# wp_redirect leading to an infinite loop

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

**Goal:** 
I have modified the permalink to show the category name for a specific category: grill-rezepte. By default the permalink is: https://website.com/post-title just the grill-rezepte is now: https://website.com/grill-rezepte/post-title

I therefore want to set up 301 redirects on all the grill recipies so that they move to the new URL. I have the following code (see below) which leads to an infinite loop.

**Code:**

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;
    // this array can contain category names, slugs or even IDs.
    $catArray = ['grill-rezepte','Test2'];
    if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "https://bbqpit.de/grill-rezepte/{$post->post_name}/";  
    wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I tried adding an if conditional

```
if (strpos($url,'grill-rezept') !== false) { 
 Above Code 
}
```

But this does not help because it seems like the redirect is placed once and is not removed on page load. So it leads to a loop. Is there any way I could fix this? From what I understand the redirect command is placed once and is left there permanently and so I can't think of any logic to over come this problem. Also, I obviously do not want to redirect (not even once, for SEO purposes) if the URL is already https://website.com/grill-rezepte/post-title

I've spent 5 hours trying to figure something out and read a lot of posts. I'm not a wordpress guru, so I'm asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: What is `$url` / how do you get it?

Comment: Oh... From what I read that's how you search within a URL for a string? So if that string is present on the URL of the current page, do not redirect. It needs to be !== false going to edit it now.

Comment: You're right. However, you need to retrieve it first, `$url` is probably empty right now (You can see that if you do something like `var_dump($url); wp_die();`). I don't have the time right now to test this myself and write a proper answer. Can you try this code `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if(strpos($url, ...` (so just prepend what you have by url = server)?

Comment: Awesome kero, that worked like a charm. Like I said at the end I'm no WordPress guru. I assumed that stuff like this was a global variable of some sort, obviously, it wasn't. If you add the same thing as a separate answer, I'd be happy to select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got most of it right. However, there is one little caveat: `$url` doesn't mean anything in your context. You can easily prove that by using something like this for debugging

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    var_dump($url);
    wp_die();
}
```

---

So all that is left for your code to work is actually defining `$url` as the requested URL (or at least the path):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;

    // this array can contain category names, slugs or even IDs.
    $catArray = ['grill-rezepte','Test2'];

    // get current path
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

    // slug is already in URL, return early
    if (strpos($url,'grill-rezept') !== false) {
        return;
    }

    if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "https://bbqpit.de/grill-rezepte/{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kero. Btw it does need to be false and not true for the logic to work if (strpos($url,'grill-rezept') == false) :) my bad on the many changes to this hehe.

Comment: @user3764238 You mean in my example it should be `== false`?

Comment: Nope, your example is good. I had to edit mine to get it to work. I should have commented on the original post, instead of here (your answer) and causing this confusion.

Comment: @user3764238 Ah I see, no worries! `strpos()` can be tricky with its return values, so I wasn't 100% sure without having to run the code myself. Glad to hear it cleared up